# Rails 5 - Access to another column than foreign key in associate table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have 3 models :

```
class Sneaker < ApplicationRecord 
    has_many :stocks
    has_many :sellers, through: :stocks
end


class Seller < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :stocks
    has_many :sneakers, through: :stocks
end


class Stock < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :sneaker
    belongs_to :seller
end
```

I have 3 tables :

- sneakers : id / brand / color
- sellers : id / name / country /
- stocks : id / sneaker_id / seller_id / old_price / price / offer_link

In a view, I try to display a list of sellers and their stocks of a sneaker (id of the sneaker in params[:id] )

In my controler, i have this :

```
@sellers = Seller.joins(:stocks).where(stocks: { sneaker_id: params[:id] })
```

But i only have access to the foreign key (sneaker_id) in the stocks table, and i want to access to other columns ( old_price, price, offer_link ).

I don't find how to write a proper query... ( maybe joins isn't the good way ? )

Comment: Look into the `.select()` ActiveRecord method. It let's you specify the fields you want to return and they can be from a joined table. If your columns are ambiguous you'll need to prefix them with the table name.

Comment: Thanks Dan for your answer, i tried with .select() and i don't have access to columns of the associate table :-/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Rails, `joins` is used only for filtering, not for accessing associated records. To include the associated records in your results, use `includes`.

```rb
@sellers = Seller.includes(:stocks).where(stocks: { sneaker_id: params[:id] })
```

Then you can access the stocks using the methods you're used to.

```rb
@sellers.first.stocks.first.old_price
```

[This article](http://blog.scoutapp.com/articles/2017/01/24/activerecord-includes-vs-joins-vs-preload-vs-eager_load-when-and-where) provides some useful details and performance considerations for `includes`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! in my view, i have a loop like this :

@sellers.each do |sellers|
 puts seller.name
 puts seller.country
 puts seller.old_price
 puts seller.price
end

is it possible to do this with includes in my controller ?

Comment: i switch to this :
@sellers = Seller.includes(:stocks).where(stocks: { sneaker_id: params[:id] })
But i still can't access to stocks column ( except foreign key ) :-/